# Argument Exception “Item with Same Key has already been added” in thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, dictionary

I have a method that is called by thread. I am having problem with the dictionary that item already exist exception. what could be the possible solution. i have provided my scenario code and changes made to overcome the problem.
The method is called by the thread.

```
public Item[] GetFolders()
{
    Dictionary<long,string> values = new Dictionary<long,string> ();
    Dictionary<long,string> values2 = new Dictionary<long,string> ();

    var remotePage = service.GetPage();

    foreach(var remotesummary in remotePage)
    {
        values2.Add(remotesummary.id, remotesummary.name);
    }

    foreach(var remotesummary in remotePage)
    {
        values.Add(remotesummary.id, remotesummary.name);
    }
}
```

Modified code to overcome the exception ""

```
public Item[] GetFolders()
{
    Dictionary<long,string> values = new Dictionary<long,string> ();
    Dictionary<long,string> values2 = new Dictionary<long,string> ();

    foreach(var remotesummary in remotePage)
    {
        var remt = remotesummary;
        values.Add(remotesummary.id, remotesummary.name);
    }

    foreach(var remotesummary in remotePage)
    {
        var remt = remotesummary;
        values2.Add(rem.id, rem.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: There's only one way to interpret the error. Why are you adding items with duplicate keys? You also seem to have posted code that does not compile.

Comment: Note that you can convert your enumeration into a dictionary in [one line](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548657(v=vs.100).aspx) with an extension method - no need for foreach and add `remotePage.ToDictionary(x => x.id, x => x.name)`. Also note that Dictionary isn't threadsafe, if you do eventually share it outside your threads, you'll need to move to `ConcurrentDictionary`

Comment: yes, this code wont compile. i am showing only the similar scenario.

Comment: @Beenodh It sounds like you have a concurrency issue, e.g. the enumerable returned by `service.GetPage()` is mutating while you are iterating it. You could materialize it into a local collection e.g. `service.GetPage().ToList();` Also, are you sure that the keys `remotesummary.id` are unique?

Answer (score 2):

You can check if that key already exists before inserting it. Add this to your code

```
if (dict.ContainsKey(key)) { ... }
```

plase note that you need to change `dict` for your variable name :D

Comment: Yes, i agree but my concern  is ..Assigning the loop data to local variable remove the exception?

Comment: No, because the problem are the keys in tje dictionary and not your variable.